# Cleaning full names into first name, last name, etc columns

Tags: string, text, sanitization, normalizing

I have a CSV file that has a single column of full names that are in different formats. Some include suffixes and initials.  There are thousands of records.

I want to break each record apart into separate columns for each part of the full name that exists.  The final columns would be:

Title

First Name

Middle Name

Last Name

Suffix

Here is an example of what some of the different names look like:

John Smith

Doe, Jane, MBA

Mrs. Sarah Johnson

Steven P Little

Fredericks, J S, D.D.S.

S Morrison, Dr Oscar

Fred Jones, M.B.A.

T. H. Gallatin

Morris Jr, Gary B.

What is a good way to break those out into separate columns given there is no standard format to the full names?

Comment: You are hosed.  For any rule you can think of, there's likely to be a counterexample somewhere.  For example, "Baron Von Trapp":  is Baron a title, or first name?  Is Von a first name, middle name, or part of the last name?  If you're required to shoehorn this input into someone else's database that requires those specific fields, you have my condolences.  If you have control over the database layout, consider just using a single "name" field, and entering it as provided, rather than trying to parse it out.

Comment: Here's a good read on the subject: http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/

Comment: Looking at that small excerpt, assuming it's representative of the whole dataset, I think the only way you could get any kind of data quality would be to split each record using space as the delimiter, and then check each field of each record against a names dictionary for surnames and forenames so you can get some accuracy. Of course you'll still get plenty of errors as plenty would have a forename as a surname and vice versa.